# Programs battery consumption in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: battery

Is there a way to know which program consume how much battery (like the following screenshot shows for Android)

[image]

in Ubuntu Desktop?

It is a command line program or with a graphical interface that's okay.

I'm currently running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 (if it care).

Comment: @MadMike I'm sorry, but I'm not interested in Ubuntu Touch, but in Ubuntu desktop!

Comment: Well then, [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/784361/edit) your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PowerTOP (https://01.org/powertop). It's not exactly whatyou want (does not give consumption percentages I think) but it gives you the wattage consumption per process in real time.

Comment: Also useful:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower#PowerTOP_Tunables